# How to delegate DNS records for 3rd-level subdomains to another DNS server, but keep 2nd-level as-is?

Tags: dns, dns-servers, namecheap

I have Namecheap BasicDNS for `example.com` and I would like Namecheap to continue to keep managing the DNS records for all of its subdomains unless I tell it otherwise.

Specifically, I want to let `mysubdomain.example.com` handle the DNS records for all of its *own* subdomains.

Is such a setup possible? Simply put, is it possible to make DNS servers "hierarchical" like this?
Or do I have to point the entire domain's nameserver toward a custom one?

Comment: I am sorry, is it just me, or am I missing something? I do not understanding what the OP is asking. Totally confused.

Comment: He's looking for [DNS subzones](https://www.google.com/search?q=dns+subzone).

Comment: "Delegate" was indeed the critical keyword I was missing :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is technically possible (it means you need to have NS records in `example.com` for handling `mysubdomain.example.com`) but it depends on the service `Namecheap` is giving you. Since you are paying them, did you ask them?
It is most probably not possible, especially for a "basicDNS" called service, but only they could answer you on this.

Comment: Yeah, they actually have it, I just didn't know about NS records! Thanks :) the one caveat seems to be (though I haven't 100% confirmed it) that the subdomain also needs to handle its *own* DNS record, which is unfortunate since half the idea was that it should be resolvable even if its DNS service crashes or something...